# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy.geocoders'; 'geopy' is not a package

Tags: python, geopy, nominatim

I am using VS and I am trying to run geopy, I installed all the prerequisites and get this error
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy.geocoders'; 'geopy' is not a package"

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="http")
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
print(location.address)
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
print(location.raw)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you install geopy through `pip install geopy`?

Comment: Yes it says already satisfied

Comment: In that case, make sure VS code is using the right python interpreter, or you are installing the package in the correct `venv` or `conda` environment (The python installation VS-code is using). I've tried your code on my machine and doesn't result in any errors.

Comment: Sorry if it is a stupid question, I am a noob with vs and python, when I check the python interpreter I only see one option "Python 3.9.1 64 bit -\appdata\local\programs\python39\python.exe" do I need to add venv or conda?

Comment: No, not perse although it has some advantages to work with environments. See for example: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-you-need-python-environments-and-how-to-manage-them-with-conda-85f155f4353c/ or https://medium.com/datareply/working-with-python-environments-anaconda-package-manager-and-ides-663e771b6ed8. Chances are that you have multiple installations of python installed. Can you open a command prompt and type `where python` and share results?

Comment: When I run where python in cmd it says" could not find files for the given pattern"

Comment: How did you run `pip install geopy`? Through venv or through command prompt? What happens if you cd (`cd "C:/PATH_TO_PYTHON`)  to directory where python is installed, and type `python` ?

Comment: I am fixing python to work on cmd first and I will update after that

Comment: I ran " py -m pip install geopy" on the VS terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem lies in you installing the `geopy` package in wrong version of python (The one that comes pre-installed in `\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` is not full install). Grab a version of python (Either anaconda or vanilla python from python website). Let it install in default location, and then point VS code  version of python that comes pre-installed with windows. Install `geopy`package thorugh pip install geopy, either with VS, or through cmd with `conda` or `pip`. This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, I did install Anaconda and install geopy by accessing CMD with Anaconda navigator but I still get this error, I do see when I open VS an alert "The environment variable 'Path' seems to have 
some paths containing characters (';', '"' or ';;'). 
The existence of such characters are known to have 
caused the Python extension to not load. If the 
extension fails to load please modify your paths to 
remove these characters." I tried to find how to solve this path issue but I really don't know what the problem is, i checked the paths and it looks good.

Comment: Where did you install Anaconda? Please paste the complete path. Did you create environment? Did you add anaconda to path when installing?

Comment: Thank you, after installing Anaconda and creating an environment it worked!

Comment: By the way I have another question maybe you will know the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67217284/geopy-scraping-yellow-pages-returns-data-but-with-partial-coordinates

Answer (score 3):

This error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy.geocoders'; 'geopy' is not a package` may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `geopy.py` and try to run it as `python geopy.py` or another file has the name `geopy.py` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where the Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module.